# How to show a checkbox in a dojo datagrid?

Tags: dojo

How to show a checkbox in a dojo datagrid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use formatter function as described in [Widgets Inside dojo.DataGrid](http://heather.koyuk.net/refractions/?p=171)
You can return new dijit.form.Checkbox from formatter function in dojo 1.4

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest setting cellType to dojox.grid.cells.Bool, instead of the formatter.The formatter gives you much freedom, but also the responsibility of gathering the data from all the checkboxes (for all the rows) afterwards. Something like this as a structure-entry should do the trick:

```js
{
   name: "is awesome?",
   width: "auto",
   styles: "text-align: center",
   type: dojox.grid.cells.Bool, editable: true
}
```

Please make sure to use a write-store (like ItemFileWriteStore) and not just a read-store, otherwise you will be disabled to actually check the checkbox :)

Answer (score 2):

You need the IndirectSelection plugin for the EnhancedGrid, here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/raybr/w3XpA/5/

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this, with Json

### HTML

```html
<table id="myGrid" dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid"
               clientSort="true" autoHeight="true" autoWidth="true">
            <script type="dojo/method">
                showFields();
            </script>
</table>
```

### DOJO

```js
    showFields:function () {
        dojo.xhrPost({
            url:"/getFields.do",
            timeout:2000,
            handleAs:"json",
            load:dojo.hitch(this, "displayInGrid")
        });
    },

    displayInGrid:function (jsonResult) {
        var dataStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore(
            { data:jsonResult }
        );
        var checkboxLayout = [
            [
                {name:'ID', field:"id" },
                {name:'Value', field:"id", formatter:this.addCheckBox}
            ]
        ];
        var grid = dijit.byId("myGrid");
        grid.setStructure(checkboxLayout);
        grid.setStore(dataStore);
    },

    addCheckBox:function (val) {
        var checkbox = "<input type='checkbox' name='myfields' value='" + val + "/>";
                    return checkbox;
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to show a checkbox selector on each row of the grid you can follow this tutorial

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/working_grid/demo/selector.php

Answer (score 0):

> If the type of the cell is a boolean, then its value is displayed as either the string true or false. If a `check box` is desired, setting the cellType to be `dojox.grid.cells.Bool` and marking it as editable will make a checkbox appear.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html#editing-cells

From markup, do like this for the desired result:

```
<th field="booleanField"  cellType="dojox.grid.cells.Bool"  editable="true">Checkbox field</th>
```