# Disable specific rows in datagrid/enhancedgrid

Tags: dojo

I want to disable one specific row in datagrid in following manner:

1) Highlight one row with a different color

2) Disable checkbox/radio button selection of that row

3) Disable inline editing of cells present in that row but allow inline editing for other rows.

Pls. help if you have any ideas.

Comment: Program it, there's no way around it as its all non-implemented features. Check these for some hacks  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222893/how-to-show-a-checkbox-in-a-dojo-datagrid?rq=1  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334614/create-a-dojo-grid-and-add-dialog-from-data-model/11399717#11399717  
I would say  
1: use CSS  
2: define your own cellType base it on checkbox with custom events  
3: define own default cellType and override cell.formatEditing(inDatum, inRowIndex) on all the cells that needs a disable (`editable` in layout is columnbased not rowbased)

Comment: The problem is that there is no unique id defined to grid rows in dojo. Else I could have easily applied some customization to that particular row.

Comment: how do you know which row you need manipulated? by store-item? by index?

Comment: I want to disable rows by store item having specific data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of the following functions to extract stuff

```
// as example, one of youre items uses identifier:'id' and 'id:10'
var identifier = '10'; 
var item = store._arrayOfTopLevelItems[10]; // you probably have this allready
var index = grid.getItemIndex(item);   // find which index it has in grid
var rowNode = grid.getRowNode(index);  // find a DOM element at that index
```

You will have the `<div>` as `rowNode`, it contains a table with cells (as many as you got columns). Set its `background-color`

The checkbox thing, you will prly know which cell-index it has

```
var cellNode = dojo.query('td[idx='+cellIndex+']', rowNode)[0];
// with cellType Bool, td contains an input
var checkbox = cellNode.firstChild;
```

Editing is another store really.. works in focus handlers. To override it, you must keep like an array of rows which you dont want editable (allthough the cell.`editable == true`).

```
function inarray(arr, testVal) {
    return dojo.some(arr, function(val) { return val == testVal }).length > 0
}
grid.setNonEditable = function (rowIndex) {
    if(! inarray(this.nonEditable,rowIndex) ) 
           this.nonEditable.push(rowIndex);
}
grid.setEditable = function (rowIndex) {
    this.nonEditable = dojo.filter(this.nonEditable, function(val) { return val != rowIndex; });
}
var originalApply = grid.onApplyEdit
grid.onApplyEdit = function(inValue, inRowIndex) {
   if(! inarray(this.nonEditable,inRowIndex) )
        originalApply.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dojox.grid.DataGrid you can use canEdit function to disable row editing or cell editing :

```
grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
    canEdit: function(inCell, inRowIndex) {
        var item = this.getItem(inRowIndex);
        var value = this.store.getValue(item, "name");
        return value == null; // allow edit if value is null
    }
}
```